# Can you enter Croatia without a visa if you have a 3-year resident permit in Germany?

Tags: visa, schengen, legal

My husband has a 3-year resident permit in Germany and with his passport he can enter any Schengen country. Can he enter Croatia with his passport?

Comment: Croatia makes this dependent on your husband's nationality, not dependent on immigration status in the Schengen zone.

Comment: @Janka actually it appears to depend on both.

Answer (score 2):

On Ministry Of Foreign and European Affairs of Republic of Croatia's [**website**](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/):

> IMPORTANT NOTICE:
>
> Pursuant to the Government’s Decision, starting with 22 July 2014, the
>   Republic of Croatia applies the Decision No 565/2014/EU. All
>   third-country nationals who are holders of valid Schengen documents,
>   as well as national visas and residence permits of Bulgaria, Cyprus,
>   and Romania do not require an additional (Croatian) visa for Croatia.

So the answer to your question is **yes**. Your husband **can enter** Croatia with his passport along with the German residence permit.